# Stop the different loop from a value

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach, break

I have a problem concerning my script which allows me to take keys and values of an array (**$array**) and to add them to an existing array (**$arraywithfourwords**).

The problem I've encountered is that when I loop over **$array**, the loop does not break when I expect it to.  In the case below, it should break when the value "A" is encountered.

*For information,* **$arraywithfourwords** *is defined from the beginning, and $array is the array taken at random and to which I attempt to "match" the keys and values of this first array.*

**$arraywithfourwords before script :**

```
[Aero] => D
[Blue] => V
[Almond] => Q
[Amazon] => X
```

**$array:**

```
[Aero] => D
[Blue] => V
[Almond] => Q
[Amazon] => X
[Android] => A   //STOP BREAK THE LOOP
[Cherry] => J    //Not continue
[Citrine] => P   //Not continue
[Dark] => M      //Not continue
[Celeste] => E   //Not continue
```

$fourthKey = [Amazon]

**Script:**

```
$passed = false;
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    if ($passed && $value != 'A' && $value != 'P')
    {
                $passed2 = 'valid';
                $arraywithfourwords[$key] = $value;

    }

    if ($key == $fourthKey && $value != 'A' && $value != 'P')
    {
                $passed = true;
    }
    if ($passed2 == 'valid') 
    {
                break;
    }

}

print_r($arraywithfourwords);
```

**$arraywithfourwords after script:**

```
[Aero] => D
[Blue] => V
[Almond] => Q
[Amazon] => X
[Cherry] => J //My problem
```

**$arraywithfourwords after script that I search:**

```
[Aero] => D
[Blue] => V
[Almond] => Q
[Amazon] => X
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? Comparing two arrays, see if one value is in the other? Merging arrays?

Comment: Koen : From the four key ​​of the $arraywithfourwords, find an array ($array) with the same keys, and add to array missing keys and values until a stop value arrives.

Comment: If the values in `$array` are the same of `$arraywithfourwords`, then you want to replace the keys of the `$arraywithfourwords` and keep a size of 4 in `$arraywithfourwords`. That's what you want ?

Comment: Still don't quite understand your case here. So you want to add only the first item from `$array` that is not in `$arrayWithFourWords`?

Comment: Kev : Yes quite. But the size of 4 can vary according to the nature of values of  $array that follow my 4 values. (y)

Comment: Koen : In this case, my script should not add anything in $arraywithfourwords. 
Because the value "A" directly follows the 4 words

Comment: what is $secondKey in your code?

Comment: looks like you should use `===` instead of `==`

Comment: lurii Drozdov : Small error fixed in script - 


$fourthKey = [Amazon]

Comment: if it should break when you encounter a value `A`, you should *make it break when it encounters a value `A`*. Right now you only break when you see `$passed2 == 'valid'` and nowhere else, so why would you even expect it to break on an `A` value? However, it looks like what you're really doing is "selecting the first four values": don't use this code, use PHP for that. There is already an [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) function, and array key/value functions, just use those.

Comment: Your example suggests you don't want `$arraywithfourwords` to actually change at all - is that really the case? What does "that I search" refer to in your final example?

Comment: Mike Kamermans : 
Array_slice is not possible here because my script is used for several array, and arrays allow a few times to have more than 4 keys...

Answer (score 0):

This will stop the loop when you find a 'stop' value :

```
$stopValues = array('A', 'P');

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  if(in_array($value, $stopValues)) {
    break;
  }
  elseif(!in_array($value, $arraywithfourwords)) { // prevent to have duplicated values
    $arraywithfourwords[$key] = $value;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this is not the purpose of my script. 
I did the test with other $array, and it replaces, when there is a duplicate, the 4 values.

Comment: You just want to know if `$array` has all the values in `$arraywithfourwords` ?

Comment: Not actually, I just want to find a way to break the loop even if it's the first word.

Comment: You want to break the loop as soon you have a value who isn't in `$arraywithfourword` ?

Comment: I want to break the loop as soon i have a value = 'A' or 'P'

Comment: Or just `if ($value == 'A' || $value == 'P') break;` if "A" and "P" really are fixed values.

Comment: Kev : We're close but that's not it. The loop does not break at 'A' firstly (see the result)

Comment: And now ? The elseif avoid to have duplicate value in $arraywithfourwords but it can extend the size of it

Comment: Kev : 
In my case, I can have two similar values ​​so I do not think empty is a good solution in this case. The result are always the same

Comment: The duplicated values in `$arraywithfourwords` will remain with the elseif, but you can't have a new one. If you want to add some potential duplicated value, you can check the key in `$arraywithfourwords` and compare it with the same key in `$array`, then if the key/value are the same you don't add the new key/value and if they are different you add the new key/value in `$arraywithfourwords`.